# How to split a line and read tokens optimally in c++

Tags: c++, split, time-complexity

I have a file, where each line consists of about 70-80 words separated by '|'. Currently, I am splitting the lines and grabbing the tokens like below:

```
   while(getline(f, lineStream)) {

      size_t pos = 0;
      while ((pos = lineStream.find('|')) != std::string::npos) {
         tokens.push_back(lineStream.substr(0, pos));
         lineStream.erase(0, pos + 1);
      }
      tokens.push_back(lineStream);
```

So, clearly, this code iterates through the whole line, and push the tokens into a vector. However, I am only interested in the first 3 tokens in each line. So, I don't want to go through the whole line. How can I read only the first 3 tokens effectively and then move to the next line. I have tried multiple things, but mostly getting segmentation error.

Comment: Please show what you tried rather than the code that you know it does not do what you want. Read about [mcve]

Comment: Add a counter?  `while(getline(f, lineStream)) {int counter = 0; while ((pos = lineStream.find('|')) != std::string::npos && counter < 3) { ...`?

Comment: Also note that `lineStream.erase(0, pos + 1);` is going to be very costly performance wise.  Instead of erasing the part of the string, you can just do `pos++;` and move along in the string.

Comment: you can use `C++17` `std::string_view` (it was added for that purpose) if performance is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a limit to number of extractions.

You may also like an optimization to avoid mutating the string on each extraction (`lineStream.erase(0, pos + 1)` invokes `memmove`):

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
for(std::string lineStream; getline(f, lineStream);) {
    int count = 3; // Extract at most 3 tokens from each line.
    for (size_t pos = 0, found;
         count-- && (found = lineStream.find('|', pos)) != std::string::npos;
         pos = found + 1)
        tokens.push_back(lineStream.substr(pos, found - pos));
}
```

Comment: `lineStream.substr`'s 2nd argument is length so it should be `lineStream.substr(pos, found-pos)`

Comment: @TeshanShanukaJ You are quite right, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of "next line" when reading a file. There is only next byte. You MUST read all the following bytes in order to figure out where the current line ends and next one begins.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to erase the previous token (it's expensive as well).
   You can `find` from the previous position+1
2. Your 2nd `tokens.push_back(lineStream);` seems to be a mistake (outside the while loop)

@Maxim's solution is quite short and nice. I'm adding this just for completion. You might want the last token even if it doesn't end with a `'|'`.

```
while(getline(f, lineStream)) {
    for (size_t i = 0, pos = 0, prev_pos = 0; i < 3; i++){
        pos = lineStream.find('|', pos);
        auto s = lineStream.substr(prev_pos, pos-prev_pos);
        if (s.empty())
            break;
        tokens.push_back(s);
        if (pos == std::string::npos)
            break;     
        pos += 1;
        prev_pos = pos;
    }
}
```